# Spring Response is Null in Angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a Spring API that returns an Authorization Bearer token in the header. I am able to see the token in the response header via browser tools. However, Angular logs the response as null. How can I access this header, so that I can save it in localStorage via client?

The Angular Code:

```
  public login(): Promise<any> {
    const user = {
      username: 'myusername',
      password: 'mypass'
    };

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', user, httpOptions)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res); // Returns null
        return res;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Spring code:

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(((User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
            .compact();
    response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);            
}
```

[image]

Comment: Presumably you're using the HttpClient and not getting a body back. See https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: Fantastic thank you!

Comment: I faced the same issue, probably your problem is in the backend side, the token is been returning but without body content. Are you using Spring Security? If yes, show me your TokenAuthenticationService that I can point you what is going on

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided by @jonrsharpe

```
      public login(): Observable<any> {
        const user = {
          username: 'username',
          password: 'password'
        };

        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
        };

        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', user, {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }), 
          observe: 'response'
        });
      }
```

or

```
  public login(): Promise<any> {
    const user = {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    };

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', user, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }), observe: 'response'
    })
      .toPromise()
      .then(results => {
        console.log(results);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```